bash completion, can one set a default word for first tab on a new terminal line
I have a container that the shell therein runs bash.  It has bash completion installed and it works fine.  This container has many custom cli commands but they all must be prefaced with nextcloud.   So if I type nex <tab> nex is unique enough to complete.
Is there a way to set a "default" completion when on a new cli line (blank) so that the first tab injects that default or I'd be ok just to inject nextcloud without a tab.
I searched around "bash completion" and the bash manpage as well as the help for complete.  I've goofed around a bit with -D, -E and based on the verbiage it seems possible but I don't see how.  Little help?
https://opensource.com/article/18/3/creating-bash-completion-script
https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash (search page for Completing)
complete: complete [-abcdefgjksuv] [-pr] [-DEI] [-o option] [-A action] [-G globpat] [-W wordlist] [-F function] [-C command] [-X filterpat] [-P prefix] [-S suffix] [name ...]
    Specify how arguments are to be completed by Readline.
    
    For each NAME, specify how arguments are to be completed.  If no options
    are supplied, existing completion specifications are printed in a way that
    allows them to be reused as input.
    
    Options:
      -p    print existing completion specifications in a reusable format
      -r    remove a completion specification for each NAME, or, if no
            NAMEs are supplied, all completion specifications
      -D    apply the completions and actions as the default for commands
            without any specific completion defined
      -E    apply the completions and actions to "empty" commands --
            completion attempted on a blank line
      -I    apply the completions and actions to the initial (usually the
            command) word
    
    When completion is attempted, the actions are applied in the order the
    uppercase-letter options are listed above. If multiple options are supplied,
    the -D option takes precedence over -E, and both take precedence over -I.
    
    Exit Status:
    Returns success unless an invalid option is supplied or an error occurs.


-W wordlist is what you need.
complete -E -W nextcloud

You may also find this approach useful: Bash "virtual" prefix terminal.
